# é possível pegar o uso da memoria RAM utilizando vuejs ou em php?

Tags: php, vue.js, memória

Olá, gostaria saber se é possível eu fazer um sistema em vuejs ou diretamente no php que pegue quantos de memoria RAM estou utilizando no total, com todos os programas.

Answer (score 0):

Com PHP em Linux você pode usar `/proc/meminfo` e retornar as informações da memória em forma de array:

```
<?php
function getSystemMemInfo(){       
    $data = explode("\n", file_get_contents("/proc/meminfo"));
    $meminfo = array();
    foreach($data as $line){
        list($key, $val) = explode(":", $line);
        $meminfo[$key] = trim($val);
    }
    return $meminfo;
}

foreach(getSystemMemInfo() as $key => $valor){
   echo "$key: $valor<br>";
}
?>
```

**Resultado:**

```
MemTotal: 24649124 kB     ← memória total
MemFree: 5182752 kB       ← memória livre
MemAvailable: 21418580 kB ← memória disponível
Buffers: 174160 kB
Cached: 13345472 kB
SwapCached: 6268 kB
Active: 10346544 kB
Inactive: 5484472 kB
Active(anon): 1571956 kB
Inactive(anon): 744208 kB
Active(file): 8774588 kB
Inactive(file): 4740264 kB
Unevictable: 23748 kB
Mlocked: 23748 kB
SwapTotal: 12287996 kB
SwapFree: 11448996 kB
Dirty: 1032 kB
Writeback: 0 kB
AnonPages: 2330460 kB
Mapped: 132848 kB
Shmem: 472 kB
Slab: 3236908 kB
SReclaimable: 2795388 kB
SUnreclaim: 441520 kB
KernelStack: 21904 kB
PageTables: 59016 kB
NFS_Unstable: 0 kB
Bounce: 0 kB
WritebackTmp: 0 kB
CommitLimit: 24612556 kB
Committed_AS: 16119768 kB
VmallocTotal: 34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed: 369736 kB
VmallocChunk: 34346323084 kB
HardwareCorrupted: 0 kB
HugePages_Total: 0
HugePages_Free: 0
HugePages_Rsvd: 0
HugePages_Surp: 0
Hugepagesize: 2048 kB
DirectMap4k: 13996 kB
DirectMap2M: 3096576 kB
DirectMap1G: 22020096 kB
```

**[Fonte: SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1455610/1377664)**

Comment: Isso serve apenas para Linux ?

Comment: Sim. Vc usa windows?

Comment: O sistema que estou desenvolvendo vai ser para as duas plataforma, por isso eu precisaria para windows e linux

Comment: algo que de 5 em 5 segundos atualizasse

Comment: O problema é que eu não tenho como testar no Windows, mas veja se esta resposta funciona: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12475735/1377664

Comment: Eu consegui fazer, obrigado pela ajuda.